How can I put indices in the frontmatter, before included chapters
I am using LaTeX to write a legal book. I would like to have my general index (of terms) at the back, but three other indices I have generated at the start (tables of statute and cases). This does not work, as the index cannot generate before the chapters are compiled. (Ie., this is what I would like, but what does not work:)
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[...]
\makeindex[name=case...]

\printindex[case] % This bit fails!

\include[...chapters...]

\printindex[main]

Is there any way of achieving the result I want? Can I compile twice? I am using Overleaf. Is there a better package? Should I just reorder the pages before printing it?

Please make your example minimal but complete, including your document class and the document environment (\begin{document} \end{document})
